# Horizontal listview with vertical text in Qml

Tags: qt, qml

**I want to create a list with Horizontal listview but vertical text. Just like this.**
[image]

**I have wrote the code,as following**

```
ListView {
    id: listView;   
    orientation: ListView.Horizontal  
    delegate: listDelegate;
    ScrollBar.horizontal: bar
    model: ListModel {
        id: phoneModel;
        ListElement{
            name: "wewqeq";
        }
        ListElement{
            name: "rrr";
        }
        ListElement{
            name: "Engine auto stop";
        }
        ListElement{
            name: "wewq";
        }
        ListElement{
            name: "weweqwe";
        }
    }
}
```

**My code showed the result that**

1. list item has Horizontal view, but the text is the same! How can i change the text orientation of ListElement?
2. The bar is at the bottom side, how can i make it to top side?

**My result like this**

[image]

Comment: if you rotate the Text element by 90/270 degrees `rotation: 90`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a vertical `ListView` and rotate it:

```
ListView {
    id: listView
    height: //...
    width: //...
    transformOrigin: Item.TopLeft
    rotation: -90
    y: listView.width
    orientation: ListView.Vertical
    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar{}
}
```

The vertical `ScrollBar` will become horizontal on the top side.

Comment: Thank you very much. But in my case, my list item resource images have been rotated! So any other method for just rotating the text?

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView {

id: listView    

delegate: listDelegate

rotation:-90 

model: ListModel {
    id: phoneModel;
    ListElement{
        name: "wewqeq";
    }
    ListElement{
        name: "rrr";
    }
    ListElement{
        name: "Engine auto stop";
    }
    ListElement{
        name: "wewq";
    }
    ListElement{
        name: "weweqwe";
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But in my case, my list item resource images have been rotated! So any other method for just rotating the text?